# Impossible to change DNS records in .DE domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I've being trying to change DNS records in a .DE domain (waverocker.de), but it's impossible! I have the same domain as .ORG and as .CH and no problem there, but with .DE version it's impossible.

Always gives back an "error while updating domain name: Nameserver error". I'm checking with https://zonemaster.net and the only red error that I get it's that my IP refers to multiple nameservers.

How can I change my DNS records in this .DE domain? Why it works fine with other domains but not with .DE?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at DeNIC's [Nameserver Predelegation Check](https://www.denic.de/en/service/tools/nast/).

Short version: your DNS servers for `waverocker.org` don't actually allow querying `waverocker.de`.

Comment: I've just checked and I've got these errors:
Warning 102 Provided glue records not applicable (NS)
waverocker.de IN NS vps139700.ovh.net /37.187.218.240

Error 107 Insufficient diversity of nameserver's IP addresses (# expected, # found)
2
1

Warning 102 Provided glue records not applicable (NS)
waverocker.de IN NS ns1.juanandjuan.com /37.187.218.240

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a single server in two different NS records for the same domain, and using the same server twice is against IANA [Technical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements).

```
NS1.JUANANDJUAN.COM.    IN      A       37.187.218.240
VPS139700.OVH.NET.      IN      A       37.187.218.240
```

> **Minimum number of name servers**
>
> There must be at least two NS records
>   listed in a delegation, and the hosts must not resolve to the same IP
>   address.
>
> **Network diversity**
>
> The name servers must be in at least two
>   topologically separate networks. A network is defined as an origin
>   autonomous system in the BGP routing table. The requirement is
>   assessed through inspection of views of the BGP routing table.

Your `.org`, `.ch` and `.net` has three nameservers, of which one has a different IP address:

```
Name Server: SDNS2.OVH.NET
Name Server: VPS139700.OVH.NET
Name Server: NS1.JUANANDJUAN.COM

sdns2.ovh.net.          IN      A       213.251.188.141
```

But, this server doesn't meet other requirement by not answering authoritatively (nor at all) for the queries: it simply isn't aware of `waverocker.org` / `.net` / `.ch` / `.de` at all.

> **Answer authoritatively**
>
> The name servers must answer authoritatively
>   for the designated zone. Responses to queries to the name servers for
>   the designated zone must have the “AA”-bit set.
>
> This will be tested by querying for the SOA record of the designated
>   zone with no “RD”-bit set.

There are two possible reasons for this to work with the other TLDs than `.de`:

1. The tests for them were made before the `sdns2.ovh.net` stopped to work as a secondary.
2. The `.de` might be more strict with the IANA requirements. The difference could be e.g. that it doesn't do a single test for each condition alone: there are two different IP addresses and two of the `NS` records are working because the single DNS server is answering authoritatively. However, the overall condition doesn't meet the requirements and there could be tests for that.

**What to do?**

- Get a working secondary and test it answers authoritatively for all your domains.
- Remove the duplicate record and only refer to `37.187.218.240` once.